# Make: execute rule dynamically

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU-Make,

Suppose I write the following:

```
.PHONY: foo bar

foo:
    $(eval foo:=1)
    @echo foo

bar:
ifneq (${foo},)
    @echo bar
endif
```

Then I make the following commands:

```
$: make foo
foo

$: make bar
bar

$: make bar foo
bar
foo

$: make foo bar
foo
bar
```

---

However, I am trying to make the following result occur for the last two commands, preferably without dropping into shell code:

```
$: make foo bar
foo

$: make bar foo
bar
foo
```

How do I cause the if guard to dynamically inhibit the `bar` rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you misuse `ifneq` --- it's always processed on the first pass, i.e. before any recipe-related stuff. So it's not an option.

Second, it's a bad design to behave differently on `make foo bar` and `make bar foo`, as it breaks parallel processing with `-jN` option. You should revise your logic: either foo must depend on bar, or bar on foo, or they must be fully independent on each other.